# Windows 8 - Windows + Tab not working - doesnt cycle windows

Tags: windows-8, hotkeys

I'm trying to figure out how to cycle through my desktop windows in Windows 8 (desktop mode windows). I think windows 7 had a really nice effect where the windows become 3D at an angle as you cycle.

Everywhere it says <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys but that does absolutely nothing for me.

Comment: what theme are you using ? If you have the transparent(areo) theme enabled it should work.

Comment: Did Windows 8 disable that feature? Please link the reference that told you to use Win+Tab.

Comment: This may interest you: http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/2626-win-tab-doesn-t-work-but-alt-tab-does.html

Comment: Check if your display driver is correctly installed and supports Aero theme.  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-key-plus-tab-key-stopped-working/ba2b8b19-d1fc-4270-b261-79c200b9d54d?auth=1